# Proving that $T:\mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation, inner-products

Let $T:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ be a linear transformation and let $u_1,u_2$ different vectors in $R^n$ such that for every $v \in \Bbb R^n$ $Tu_1  \cdot v = Tu_2 \cdot v$.

Prove that $T$ is not surjective.

I'm clueless about where to begin, some help please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$(Tu_1-Tu_2)\cdot v=0$ for every $v\in\Bbb R^n$, that is, $Tu_1-Tu_2$ is orthogonal to all vectors in the space, *including itself*.

What is the consequence?

Comment: I might be missing something but the consequence of your lines is that $T$ is not injective! But he asked for surjective (onto) !

Comment: Thanks :) I finally realized I could pick $v=(T(u_1)-T(u_2))$.

Comment: @LeoSera If a linear endomorphism is not injective, it is not surjective either, because its matrix is singular.

Comment: Thanks !! I was missing something !! Sorry for the interruption.